# Ideas for 404/captcha/error images

Tags: discussion, design

Hi All,

As I'm finalizing the CSS conversion of the Math design, I need your help on the images for the 404/Captcha/error pages. You can see the ones I used on the other StackExhange sites.

The idea is to keep it related to the site's topic, but also a bit light-hearted. For example, for **Gaming site**:
Captcha [image]

404[image]

For **Cooking site**:

404 [image]

Error [image]

You can append /error, /404, /captcha to see the images from the other newly graduated Stack Exchange sites.

**So, what should I use for the Math site?** I think it'd be clever to use some in-joke type of math comic strips, assuming they're ok for us to use copy-right wise.

Comment: I think using the "does not exist" symbol ($\not\exists$) for the 404 page would either be really neat or really lame, but I can't tell which. (It would certainly be very hard to make a pretty image out of, which is why I'm not posting this as a serious suggestion.)

Comment: @Rahul, it doesn't have to be "pretty." The goal is for the users of the site to "get it." An inside joke if you will. I think your suggestion is great.

Comment: For errors, probably the usual suspects e.g. "you divided by zero!"? For the CAPTCHA, display a calculus problem first and then "just kidding, here's the actual CAPTCHA..."

Comment: @J.M. that's pretty clever! can you find a complex calculus formula? maybe i'll put it on blackboard graphic. I think it'd be fitting, since I'm removing the blackboard treatment from the badges.

Comment: I have quite the number of beasts in my stable, and I'll have to look over them to see what's appropriate @Jin. In the meantime, I believe the others have their own monsters they might like to see! (I was thinking of this replacing the "hello fellow robot" image one sees in the CAPTCHA).

Comment: Now I think about something like Venn diagrams. The set of MSE pages and showing that you are out of it. Some kind of figure is better than a symbol, more interesting to view. BTW look at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/404

Answer (score 15):

Following Jin's encouragement, I'm posting my comment as an answer so people can vote on it.

For the 404 page: The "does not exist" symbol.
$$\LARGE\unicode{x2204}$$

Comment: Wouldn't $\neg\exists$ be better?

Answer (score 5):

How about the slogan:
"404 is not a very interesting number"

referring to the Ramanujan-Hardy taxi story.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [this XKCD comic](http://xkcd.com/329/) for the captcha?

[image: XKCD #329]

Or maybe it's not math-related enough.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematical fallacy for 500 (/error)? For example,

\begin{align}
a &= b \\\\
a^2 &= ab \\\\
a^2 - b^2 &= ab - b^2 \\\\
(a+b)(a-b) &= b(a-b) \\\\
a+b &= b \\\\
a+a &= a \quad (∵ a=b) \\\\
2a &= a \\\\
2 &= 1\quad?!
\end{align}

References:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_fallacy
- [`[fake-proofs]`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fake-proofs) and [`[fake-paradoxes]`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fake-paradoxes) tags.

Comment: I like the idea behind this (so +1), but is there a less traditional and not very transparent fallacy we can use?

Comment: @JM: Maybe we could take some material from the [ `fake-proofs` ](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fake-proofs) and [ `fake-paradoxes` ](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fake-paradoxes) tags.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a rival for $\nexists$, namely the empty set:

$$\LARGE\varnothing$$

Now I wonder if ⊥ was considered for 404 at theoretical computer science.

Comment: I really hope not.

Answer (score 2):

For CAPTCHA:

> In the text field below, give a proof that for integers $n \ge 3$, there do not exist integers $x,y,z$ with $x^n + y^n = z^n$.

Comment: Fermat's Last Theorem? shouldn't it be `n>=2` ?

Comment: @Aarthi Recall the $(3,4,5)$ triangle and other [Pythagorean triples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple). One should also exclude trivial solutions such as $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,0,1)$.

Comment: Ah ha. I stand corrected, which is totally understandable. :D

Comment: HaHA, that would be the best CAPTCHA ever..

Answer (score -6):

May be something about "Divide by zero" for the [error page](https://math.stackexchange.com/error)?

[image: Recursive "Divide by zero" macro]

[image: Waterfall "Divide by zero" macro]